# How to change the behavior of a python dictionary's __setattr__?

Tags: python, types, dictionary, customization, internals

In Python, everything has a class. Therefore `dict` also has a class.

So, in theory, I should be able to change the implementation of the keyvalue assignment behavior.

**Example:**

```py
d = dict()
d['first'] = 3    # Internally d['first'] is stored as 6 [i.e. value*2 if value is INT]

print d['first']  # should print 6

d['second'] = 4 

print d['second'] # should print 8
```

I noticed that most objects have attributes listed in `OBJECT.__dict__` or `vars(OBJECT)`. But this isn’t the case for `dict` or `list`.

How can I get the desired behavior by overriding `dict.__setattr__()` method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is `__setitem__` that have to be overriden in this case - 
and it is as simples as:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
         dict.__setitem__(self, key, 2 * value)
```

Example:

```
>>> m  = MyDict()
>>> m[0] = 5
>>> m
{0: 10}
```

`__setattr__` controls how object attributes themselves (not key/value pairs) are attributed.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for .... On the same note, can I assume, key and value are attributes in the dict() class. If yes, is there a way to find that out(other than looking at the source code) like vars(object) etc. I ask so that if I wanted to change the behavior of say lists, or tuples.

Comment: As the other answers note, you can't change the behavior of the builtin types, like dicts or lists - but you can either subclass then, or create your own classes with ay desired behavior. The best document  to read and understand which methods should be implemented for each behavior you want is Python's data model: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html .

Answer (score 8):

Be careful when subclassing `dict`. If you just override `__setitem__`, then other `dict` methods, such as `update`, will not call your `__setitem__`.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
         dict.__setitem__(self, key, 2 * value)

d = MyDict()
d['first'] = 3
print(d['first'])
# 6

d.update({'first':4})
print(d['first'])
# 4                       # <--- __setitem__ was not called.
```

In order to create a dict-like object, you either need to subclass `dict` and override all the methods (see [OrderedDict](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) for an example of this approach), or subclass `collections.MutableMapping` and override a small subset those methods (from which all the other methods are derived).

```
import collections

class MyDict2(collections.MutableMapping,dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
         dict.__setitem__(self, key, 2 * value)
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        dict.__delitem__(self, key)
    def __iter__(self):
        return dict.__iter__(self)
    def __len__(self):
        return dict.__len__(self)
    def __contains__(self, x):
        return dict.__contains__(self, x)

d = MyDict2()
d['first'] = 3
print(d['first'])
# 6
d.update({'first':4})
print(d['first'])
# 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can’t. The `dict` class is <strike>written in C</strike> a Python builtin, which means you <strike>can’t</strike> really shouldn’t do any kind of monkey-patching on it.

You can, however, inherit from it and override whatever methods you want in your subclass.

Comment: Well, it's safer to say that `dict` is a built-in and that's why you can't change it. Implementation doesn't have to be CPython.

Comment: Very true, yes -- I made an assumption that this is CPython. I have absolutely no idea if Jython or Iron Python and the likes would let you do this. However since CPython is kind of the "gold standard" I'm guessing that writing code with varying behavior is, at the least, undesirable. So it would be best not to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I don't plan to do any such thing, just trying to understand the internals :)

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following code in the console you will see that the dict class/object is read-only:

```
{}.__setitem__ = None
AttributeError: 'dict' object attribute '__setitem__' is read-only
```

You need to what @jsbueno posted, which is create a subclass of the dict class, override the `__setitem__` method, multiply the value by two and then call the original dict `__setitem__` method.