# How to make dictionary read-only?

Tags: python, dictionary, readonly, readonly-collection

I have a class like:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
```

and at some moment I want to prohibit `self.data` fields modification.

I've read in [PEP-416 rejection notice](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0416/#rejection-notice) that there are a lot of ways to do it. So I'd like to find what they are.

I tried this:

```
a = A()
a.data = types.MappingProxyType(a.data)
```

That should work but first, its python3.3+ and second, when I do this "prohibition" multiple times I get this:

```
>>> a.data = types.MappingProxyType(a.data)
>>> a.data = types.MappingProxyType(a.data)
>>> a.data
mappingproxy(mappingproxy({}))
```

though it would be much better to get just `mappingproxy({})` as I am going to "prohibit" a lot of times. Check of `isinstance(MappingProxyType)` is an option, but I think that other options can exist.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752451/how-to-change-the-behavior-of-a-python-dictionarys-setattr may help you

Comment: A frozendict implementation looks rather trivial: https://github.com/slezica/python-frozendict/blob/master/frozendict/__init__.py

Comment: @codelover Thats right, I can override `__setitem__` with `throw NotImplemented`. Is there guarantee that there will be no way to modify keys or values via any standard `dict` attributes in any python implementation?

Comment: @sshilovsky Nope, instead you could derive an user dict and override whatever & you can use where ever it is applicable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would a "frozen dict" be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703599/what-would-a-frozen-dict-be)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [`collections.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping) e.g.

```
import collections

class DictWrapper(collections.Mapping):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def __getitem__(self, key): 
        return self._data[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data)
```

Comment: Can it be that this only makes the dict itself, but not necessarilty contained dicts immutable? I currently want to make a nested dict representing a config immuatable.

Comment: I think it works exactly like you describe already. `dict_wrapper[key]` returns whatever you've put there, which might as well be a raw `dict`.

Comment: Great answer!  It's worth mentioning:

(1) Modern python wants `collections.abc.Mapping`, not `collections.Mapping` which has been deprecated.

(2) `collections.abc.Mapping` simply doesn't have `__setitem__` or ilk methods defined, so attempts to store data to the mapping will result in a `TypeError` exception.

(3) If you want something to make an entire tree of dictionaries read-only, you need to make `__gititem__` return a read-only wrapper for lists and dicts.  Additionally, you'll need to define a read-only iterator for `__iter__` to return.

Answer (score 40):

This is the full implementation of fast (shallow-)read-only dict:

```
def _readonly(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot modify ReadOnlyDict")

class ReadOnlyDict(dict):
    __setitem__ = _readonly
    __delitem__ = _readonly
    pop = _readonly
    popitem = _readonly
    clear = _readonly
    update = _readonly
    setdefault = _readonly
```

My previous (worse) implementation was as follows (thanks @mtraceur for the great remarks!):

```
class ReadOnlyDict(dict):
    def __readonly__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError("Cannot modify ReadOnlyDict")
    __setitem__ = __readonly__
    __delitem__ = __readonly__
    pop = __readonly__
    popitem = __readonly__
    clear = __readonly__
    update = __readonly__
    setdefault = __readonly__
    del __readonly__
```

Comment: To allow for copying them using `copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy` you might want to add the following two lines: `__copy__ = dict.copy` and `__deepcopy__ = copy._deepcopy_dispatch.get(dict)`.
Not much tested though.

Comment: right, but how to initialize this or how to make existing dict use this?

Comment: ```ro_dict = ReadOnlyDict(rw_dict)```

Comment: Doing `del __readonly__` will mess with pickling of the methods, both unbound and bound, if that even comes up. Also all names of the form `__*__` are reserved by Python, and are free to break at any time. So I would call it `_readonly`, define it outside the class, and just leave it in the module it's defined in instead of `del`-ing it. (*Bound* which are that function will still be unpickleable, but that's due to a weirdly broken approach in Python's pickling of bound methods - unbound references to those methods will be pickleable.)

Comment: Cheers, just noticed the edit, happy to help!

Comment: this does not reflect updates, consider - https://gist.github.com/nduhamel/748954 instead

Answer (score 11):

Very easy, you just override default dict's methods!
Here is an example:

```
class ReadOnlyDict(dict):

    __readonly = False

    def readonly(self, allow=1):
        """Allow or deny modifying dictionary"""
        self.__readonly = bool(allow)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):

        if self.__readonly:
            raise TypeError, "__setitem__ is not supported"
        return dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):

        if self.__readonly:
            raise TypeError, "__delitem__ is not supported"
        return dict.__delitem__(self, key)
```

BTW, you can also remove `.pop`, `.update` and other methods you need. Just play around with it.

Comment: How do you apply this "at some moment"? I guess OP needs the dict to be read-write, then make it frozen after some time.

Comment: If he needs, he can modify them too

Comment: This approach is obvious but is not simple as I have to override almost each `dict` method and even reimplement `dict` views like `.keys()`, `.items()` etc. And what if Guido adds some more in future python versions? Anyway, thanks for the point, but I wish there were more answers.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to derive from `UserDict` like this:

```
from collections import UserDict

class MyReadOnlyDict(UserDict):
   def my_set(self, key, val, more_params):
       # do something special
       # custom logic etc
       self.data[key] = val

   def __setitem__(self, key, val):
       raise NotImplementedError('This dictionary cannot be updated')

   def __delitem__(self, key):
       raise NotImplementedError('This dictionary does not allow delete')
```

The advantage of this method is that you can still have internal methods in your class that can update dictionary by accessing `self.data`.

Comment: What about `instance = MyReadOnlyDict(); instance.data['a'] = 'b'`

Answer (score 1):

How about? It is the update of @mouad 's answer.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections.abc import Mapping


class ReadOnlyJsonObject(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, data, dumps_kw: dict=None, loads_kw: dict=None):
        if dumps_kw is None:
            dumps_kw = dict()
        if loads_kw is None:
            self._loads_kw = dict(object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        else:
            self._loads_kw = loads_kw

        if isinstance(data, str):
            self._json_string = data
        else:
            self._json_string = json.dumps(data, **dumps_kw)

    @property
    def _data(self):
        return json.loads(self._json_string, **self._loads_kw)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._data[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._json_string
```

Not sure about the performance, though. I use this one in a real project https://github.com/patarapolw/AnkiTools/blob/master/AnkiTools/tools/defaults.py

Answer (score 0):

Belated answer. You can use a combination of property and MappingProxyType to protect the `.data` field from modifications.

```py
from types import MappingProxyType

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    @property
    def data(self):
        return MappingProxyType(self._data)

    def update(self, key, value):
        self._data[key] = value

a = A()
a.update("foo", 1)
a.update("bar", 2)
print(f"a.data={a.data}")

# Attempt to modify a.data directly will fail
try:
    a.data["bar"] = 20
except TypeError as error:
    print(f"Error: {error}")

# Attempt to assign something else to a.data, will also fail
try:
    a.data = {}
except AttributeError as error:
    print(f"Error: {error}")
```

Output:

```
a.data={'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
Error: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment
Error: property 'data' of 'A' object has no setter
```

#### Notes

- The `A.data` is not a regular attribute, it is a property. Since there is no setter, it is also a read-only property.
- `A.data` returns a `MappingProxy` instead of the dictionary itself. That means code outside of the class will not be able to modify the dictionary's contents.
- In order to modify the dictionary, I added the method `update()` as an example
- If people want to, they can modify `A._data` directly, there is nothing we can do to prevent that.