# How to store a collection of constants that can be called by Collection.variable?

Tags: python, python-3.9, namedtuple, python-class, python-collections

I'm searching for a `collection` that can be used to store multiple constants and also can be used to get a list of them?

EDIT: It does not have to be constants, it can be variables.

I want to get a value this way:

```
Constants.first_one
```

But also get a list of values like:

```
Constants.values
```

Which returns something like:

```
['First one', 'Second one' .... ]
```

Using a `class` and `class attributes` is good for the first usage but not for the second one:

```
class Constants:
    first_one = 'First one'
    second_one = 'Second one'
```

To get a list of attributes I'd need to make a method that does that.

I'm also considering named tuple but I again don't know how to get the list of values:

```
class Constants(typing.NamedTuple):
    first_one = 'First one'
    second_one = 'Second one'
```

EDIT:

`Enum` does not seem to have such option neither and moreover I need to get values this way `Constants.first_one.value`

EDIT2:

Basically, all I want is to know if there is some collection that behaves like this:

```
class Properties:
    PHONE = 'phone'
    FIRSTNAME = 'firstname'
    LASTNAME = 'lastname'

    @classmethod
    @property
    def values(cls):
        return [x for x in dir(cls) if not x.startswith('__') and x != 'values']


print(Properties.PHONE)
> phone
print(Properties.FIRSTNAME)
> firstname
print(Properties.values)
> ['phone', 'firstname', 'lastname']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make dictionary read-only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022868/how-to-make-dictionary-read-only-in-python)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't think so. It does not have to be non-editable but I want to be able to call values as attributes (not by getitem) as I want IDE to autocomplete the variables.

Comment: Then I got the word "constant" wrong. For me, a constant is non-editable. The IDE syntax highlighting and autocompletion is also an aspect that is not mentioned in the question yet.

Comment: [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) may be related: it lists all names. You just need to exclude the dunder ones (`__`)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, that's one way to do that. I was curious if there is something built-in or some module that does that. I've added an example at the bottom of the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Given that no one answered yet heres my two cents:

###### A) You're going the wrong way around.

Instead of a @property returning a list of your attributes, implement a `__getattr__`/`__setattr__` to access your stored data by attribute (by dot-notation).

###### B) Take a look at something called a 'bunch'.

Bunches are a subclass of a dict, that expose their content as attribute *while retaining the benefits of a dictionary*. E.g. they provide the .values() method, allow key-access *and* attribute-access, and they are true dictionaries. There are multiple libraries implementing their own versions of it, for example "bunch" on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/bunch/) or [github](https://github.com/dsc/bunch).

##### Example

The easiest implementation of a bunch, which I can come up with, is done by mangling the instance into its own `__dict__` slot. Given its simplicity, I imagine it being somewhat common, even though it is certainly not the best:

```
class Bunch(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Bunch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # make us behave like a dict
        self.__dict__ = self  # we are our namespace => dict_access IS attr_access
```

A better version would add the actual data in a (possibly private) attribute and implement custom `__getattr__`/`__setattr__`/`__delattr__` as mentioned above. This need no longer be a 'bunch', and indeed in your case a bunch would probably be unnecessary...

```
class NotABunchCollection:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data = dict(*args, **kwargs)
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        """attribute-access. Only called if key is not found in normal places."""
        try:
            return self.data[key]
        except KeyError:  # missing keys => attribute error, not key error
            raise AttributeError(key)
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        """To attribute-style assign"""
        self.data[key] = value
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        """To attribute-style delete"""
        del self.data[key]
    def values_list(self):
        """Wraps values to a list. could also be a @property"""
        return list(self.data.values())
```

... *but* as stated above in B) there are libraries that do that for you. The 'bunch' type would solve your problem (even my crude one) and the 'bunch'-library mentioned above would add functionality you might find useful (like 'bunchify', 'to_yaml', 'from/to dict', etc.).

There may also be options with pydantic or with data classes.

Answer (score 0):

The `collections.namedtuple` almost fit your definition, except for an alternate way to get the values.

```py
import collections


def make_collection(**kwargs):
    Blueprint = collections.namedtuple("Collection", kwargs)
    collection = Blueprint(**kwargs)
    return collection


contact = make_collection(
    PHONE="phone",
    FIRSTNAME="firstname",
    LASTNAME="lastname",
)

print(f"Contact: {contact}")
print(f"Phone: {contact.PHONE}")
print(f"First Name: {contact.FIRSTNAME}")
print(f"Last Name: {contact.LASTNAME}")
print(f"Values: {list(contact)}")
print(f"Fields: {contact._fields}")
print(f"As Dictionary: {contact._asdict()}")
```

Output:

```
Contact: Collection(PHONE='phone', FIRSTNAME='firstname', LASTNAME='lastname')
Phone: phone
First Name: firstname
Last Name: lastname
Values: ['phone', 'firstname', 'lastname']
Fields: ('PHONE', 'FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME')
As Dictionary: {'PHONE': 'phone', 'FIRSTNAME': 'firstname', 'LASTNAME': 'lastname'}
```

#### Notes

- The `make_collection` function is there for your convenient. It provides a simple way to return a named tuple
- In order to get a list of values, just call `list()` on the collection